# Unable to enumerate USB device on Ubuntu server 19.10 arm64 at Raspberry Pi 4B

Tags: raspberrypi, 19.10

I tried to`modprobe usb-storage` and `modprobe scsi_mod` but it not working,and I try to use `tail -f /var/log/syslog` and got this:

```
Oct 21 15:48:30 Raspi kernel: [  815.178786] usb usb2-port1: attempt power cycle
Oct 21 15:48:31 Raspi kernel: [  816.106888] usb 2-1: new SuperSpeed Gen 1 USB device number 12 using xhci_hcd
Oct 21 15:48:31 Raspi kernel: [  816.127630] usb 2-1: device descriptor read/8, error -61
Oct 21 15:48:31 Raspi kernel: [  816.238625] usb 2-1: new SuperSpeed Gen 1 USB device number 12 using xhci_hcd
Oct 21 15:48:31 Raspi kernel: [  816.259615] usb 2-1: device descriptor read/8, error -61
Oct 21 15:48:32 Raspi kernel: [  816.594824] usb 2-1: new SuperSpeed Gen 1 USB device number 13 using xhci_hcd
Oct 21 15:48:32 Raspi kernel: [  816.615660] usb 2-1: device descriptor read/8, error -61
Oct 21 15:48:32 Raspi kernel: [  816.726625] usb 2-1: new SuperSpeed Gen 1 USB device number 13 using xhci_hcd
Oct 21 15:48:32 Raspi kernel: [  816.747639] usb 2-1: device descriptor read/8, error -61
Oct 21 15:48:32 Raspi kernel: [  816.886805] usb usb2-port1: unable to enumerate USB device
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Raspberry Pi 4B is not supported under Ubuntu 19.04 (Disco). The first version with 4B support is Ubuntu 19.10 (Eoan), though I'm hoping to get support back-ported to the current LTS (18.04, Bionic) as soon as possible.

If you have a 19.04 installation and wish to upgrade, that upgrade should be performed on a platform supported by 19.04, e.g. a Raspberry Pi 3B. After upgrade, the image *should* be bootable on a 4B; if it is not, that's a bug - please let me know!

However, be aware there is currently a known issue with the USB ports under the `arm64` image on the Raspberry Pi 4B:

[USB not working under arm64 on Pi4](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux-raspi2/+bug/1848790)

A [workaround](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux-raspi2/+bug/1848790/comments/9) is mentioned in that report, but you may wish to stick to the `armhf` variant for now (`armhf` uses LPAE, so you'll still have access to all the RAM on the Pi4).

Comment: Thanks, it's my mistake, actually the ubuntu server version is 19.10, and I got the same problem on usb, thank you for your help